# Creating a "warning" when trying to calculate X/0

Tags: c#, calculation

I want to make a calculator that asks what you want to do, e.g. add, subtract, etc. It should then use if-statements to perform the different kinds of calculations.

But now when I have gotten to division, I'm wondering how to handle division by 0. I want the program to warn the user when he/she enters a `0`, saying something like  "sorry you can't divide by `0`".

I still want it to calculate the result if the denominator isn't 0.

The error i get is that i can't write:

`if (Num02 == "0")` because I can't use ints or doubles etc.

How do I fix this in a nice way to show my class/teacher next week?

Here's my code:

```
using System;

namespace Calculator
{        
    class MainClass
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Start:
            int Num01;
            int Num02;
            string Answer;
            Console.WriteLine("What do you want to do?");

            Answer = Console.ReadLine();

            if (Answer == "Division")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Write number");

                Num01 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Divided by?");

                Num02 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                 Console.WriteLine(Num01 + "/" + Num02 + "=" + 
                                      (Num01 / Num02));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using Convert try using [int.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number).

Comment: What you've tried is almost there. Instead, remove the quotes around the `0`, because `num02` IS an `int`

Comment: "because i cant use ints or doubles etc." -- Why not? Is this about the compiler error you're getting, or a requirement in your assignment? If the former, please include the complete error message in your question (copy & paste!). That helps others explain not only the error, but also how to read the error message. If the latter, can you be more specific about what is and isn't allowed? `Num01` and `Num02` are `int` variables, so it does not appear to be a blanket ban.

Comment: I'll keep the "provide the errors" thing in mind next time. there arent any errors anymore, so i would say jeroenh's answer fixed it. But thanks anyway all of you.

And for the "try using int.TryParse()" thing. Thats a bit over my level right now, but I think my teacher is going to teach that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the error i seem to get is that i cant write:
>
> "if (num02 == "0")" because i cant use ints or doubles etc.

You were most certainly on the right track. By adding quotes around the "0", you were comparing a variable of type `int` (`Num02`) with a `string`. Instead, use a literal `0` (without quotes):

```
if (Num02 == 0)
{
   // print warning here
}
else
{
   // do division and print result
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It didnt even interfere with the other operations! Again, Thank you. You really saved me :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest *extracting method* for the user input (where we can check *syntax* - what if user put `bla-bla-bla` instead of number, extra condition(s) - we don't accept `0` as a second number etc.):

```
private static int ReadValue(string title, 
                             Func<int, bool> extraCondition = null, 
                             string extraConditionText = null) {
  int result;

  while (true) { // keep on asking until correct input provided
    Console.WriteLine(title); 

    if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result)) // syntax check
      Console.WriteLine("Syntax error, please, input integer value");
    else if (extraCondition != null && !extraCondition(result)) // extra check if any
      Console.WriteLine(string.IsNullOrEmpty(extraConditionText) 
        ? "Incorrect value" 
        : extraConditionText);
    else 
      return result;
  }
}
```

Then you can put

```
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    while (true) {
      int Num01;
      int Num02;

      Console.WriteLine("What do you want to do?");

      string Answer = Console.ReadLine().Trim();  

      if (string.Equals(Answer, "Quit", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
        break;
      }
      else if (string.Equals(Answer, "Division", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
        Num1 = ReadValue("Write number");
        Num2 = ReadValue("Divided by?", x => x != 0, "Sorry you can't divide by 0");

        Console.WriteLine($"{Num1} / {Num2} = {Num1 / Num2}");
      }           
      else {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, it's an incorrect option");
      } 
   }
 }
```

Comment: I'll show my teacher this on Tuesday so he can explain it a bit further for me.

If he can help me, I'll definatly try it out :).